# Giving an explicit type to a number

Tags: types, casting, rust

Typing a number in Rust code, e.g.

```
a = 12
```

interprets the number as an i32. Is there any way to write that number as an i16 for example?

I'm looking for something such as adding an L to the number, e.g. `12L`, to 'make' it a `long` type, such as is done in C.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#integer-literals

Comment: @Stefan: I see no mention [in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/primitive-types.html) though :x

Comment: TIL they're called literals. I wonder if anything would make this question _not_ deserve downvotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
5i16
```

Rust's integer suffixes are just the primitive type name.

Comment: Why someone put -1? This is the right answer. I prefer typing `5_i16` to distinguish the number and the type personally.